# json decode array PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode a json string, i want to get just langlinks value,
my json string is:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "105219": {
                "pageid": 105219,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Cancer",
                "langlinks": [
                    {
                        "lang": "ar",
                        "*": "\u0633\u0631\u0637\u0627\u0646"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this code:

```
$results = json_decode($api_response, true);
$list = array();
foreach ($results['query']['pages'] as $k => $v)
{
    var_dump($v);
    foreach($v as $key => $val)
    {
       array_push($list, $val);
    } 
}

return $list;
```

But it does not accede to the value that I want, when i add

```
var_dump(array_key_exists('langlinks', $v));
```

it gives me false :/

Comment: Well, what does `var_dump($v)` give you?

Comment: var_dump($v) gives me      array (size=3)
  'pageid' => int 105219
  'ns' => int 0
  'title' => string 'Cancer' (length=6)

Comment: Then, yeah, you're looking at the right array, but there's no `langlinks` in there. Are you 100% sure it's in the `$api_response`...?

Comment: yes i'm sure, i dont understand why there is no langlinks

Comment: when i add $results['query']['pages']['105219'] it gives me Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: **Are. You. SURE. The. API. Response. Contains. The. Data. You. Think. It. Contains?!**

Comment: yes , it's the result of this request : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Cancer&prop=langlinks&lllang=ar

Comment: Does *your* `$api_response` actually contain the same data?!

Comment: Maybe you need to use `$val` instead of `$v` as `array_key_exists` is not recursive. `var_dump(array_key_exists('langlinks', $val));`

Comment: var_dump($api_response);  gives string '{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"105219":{"pageid":105219,"ns":0,"title":"Cancer","langlinks":[{"lang":"ar","*":"\u0633\u0631\u0637\u0627\u0646"}]}}}}' (length=156)  and var_dump(array_key_exists('langlinks', $val));  gives array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given

Comment: maybe interesting? Seems to work here: https://eval.in/617475

Comment: Okey thank you.. that's can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and this seems to return `true`

```
$source = file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Cancer&prop=langlinks&lllang=ar&format=json');
$results = json_decode($source, true);

foreach ($results['query']['pages'] as $k => $v)
{
    var_dump(array_key_exists('langlinks', $v));die();
}
```

If you are still having trouble, maybe you can post more code?

Comment: Allright, is your code returning `true` aswell now?

Answer (score -2):

```
    $list = array();
    $src = json_decode($api_response, true);


     foreach ($src['query']['pages'] as $key => $langData) {
       foreach ($langData['langlinks'] as $k => $ld);
          // var_dump($ld['*']);
           }

     return $ld['*'];
```

Comment: The inner loop is not doing anything because of the semicolon at the end of the line.